# How to make a mention to a user in a slack message from Workflow Builder when the username/ID comes from a variable

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm trying to make a workflow for my slack team where I have these steps (with workflow builder):

- Starts when user clicks on the shortcut in a channel
- Opens a form - we ask many questions, one question has multiple fixed choices
- Select row from Google Sheets - depending on the answer, we select a row
- Send a message to a slack channel - Use the value from another column of the same row that contains a slack memberID (or username) to mention the person on the message

I expected the slack message on the channel to have @userHere as a mention (triggering the notifications). However, the message was sent on the channel with @userHere as a plain string i.e. not clickable and it does not trigger a notification.

What I tried:

| what I put in the send message step | what is saved in the sheet |
| --- | --- |
| @variable | "user.name" |
| @variable | "U123213" |
| variable | "@user.name" |
| variable | "@U123213" |
| {{variable}} | @user.name |

among other attempts, but I never get the mention.

Comment: did you find any workaround?

Comment: Not yet... it seems something simple.. but i can't find a workarount...

Comment: I am looking for the exact same solution.
Have you ever find the solution?
Any workaround you did?

Answer (score 0):

If using webhooks, you can add a "Slack user email" variable in the workflow and then add that variable to the "Message text" with Mention (default) option selected.

---

#### Webhook settings

[image: Webhook settings]

---

#### Send a message settings

[image: Send a message settings]

Answer (score -3):

when posting from the SLACK API I believe the correct code for an @ is to wrap it in angled brackets

<@user_id>

So in the case where you input was of the form

```
{{variable}}
```

Then it should translate the variable appropriately.

Comment: I just get {{<@U0452BNJR7V>}} as plain text...